# Проверяющий или рецензент?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, локализация, очередь-проверок

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На той же SOen там одно и то же:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может остановимся на одном варианте?

Comment: Тут еще старинный косяк с выравниванием: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288893/339911 Но всем плевать.

Comment: @alexolut:  Читаю сейчас [Nonviolent Communication: A Language of Life](https://www.amazon.com/Nonviolent-Communication-Language-Marshall-Rosenberg/dp/1892005034), рекомендую (для себя). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LuPCAh9FCc

Comment: @jfs ...o_O....

Answer (score 6):

Проблема известная, да. Предлагаю остановиться на проверяющем: мы все-таки не рецензируем научные статьи, а всего лишь просматриваем очередь *проверок* и замечаем, что не так, если что не так.

Comment: Рецензент отдаёт клерикализмом каким-то. Я тоже за проверяющего.

Answer (score 0):

мне кажется что это "Редактор", по аналогии журналами или газетами

Comment: Тогда уж "Утверждатор" )

Comment: @Suvitruf нет такого слова. Ваш ход переходит к другому.